# How to convert Git LFS files to object files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a file in git, that is stuck as a pointer to an object. It has the version, oid, and size specified properly. But whenever I call `git lfs pull` or `git lfs fetch` or `git lfs fetch --all` the file stays the same.

My co-worker pushed up the file as part of a merge conflict with their stash. So the file originally read something like

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
oid sha256:5a600ddad19d46be15edef3d14ccbd66f59b47b0a97bafd70867bb04ce34acd5
size 8485382
=======
oid sha256:209c96e98a5264c6e8cc9038bffa9b4ba7f9b2da2afe6c62bc7b5915ee1ce25f
size 8753323
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

to try and pull down their changes, I simply "amended" the conflict by deleting the Updated Stream. So the file now reads as such:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:209c96e98a5264c6e8cc9038bffa9b4ba7f9b2da2afe6c62bc7b5915ee1ce25f
size 8753323
```

I know they did not push up properly. But what's done is done, is there a way I can pull down whatever they had stashed and tried pushing up?

Comment: These "pointer files" are the only thing Git actually stores. LFS is an add-on wrapper that runs *outside* (or in some cases, "next to") Git: it intercepts the "large" files and gives Git the pointer files instead, and it intercepts the pointer files and puts the large files into your working tree instead. I don't like or use Git-LFS myself so I have no recipe for you to use, but you're doing the right kind of thing here: you just need, now, for Git-LFS to do the desired file substituting, in the desired cases.

Comment: It seems to me that in this case, my coworker edited the file and only "pushed" to their local stash. And so the reference link must be stored only in their local repository, when they merged, it didn't wrangle the two pointers well, and so when they pushed, I believe that it never knew to push the lfs pointer file to remote. So in that case the LFS file still only exists on their local machine and will somehow need to be pushed up from their local machine in order for the rest of us to retrieve it. But that's just my current theory.